# Mysql InnoDB exsited but can't show it

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a InnoDB table A ,

While I type "show tables" , I can't see it. Even I type "drop table A" , it responses "table doesn't exist" .

While I create a table B which refers from A , table B can be created.

result : I can't do any operations to A and can't see it , but I can use other table refers to A.

Please help me to see the table A.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

"show tables" reads .frm files, so A.frm exists.
DROP TABLE however tries to remove a record about this table from the InnoDB dictionary. And it fails because apparently there is no such record in the dictionary.

Depending on innodb_file_per_table option the table is stored either in ibdata1 or in A.ibd.

I suggest you to remove A.frm file (move it to safe place) and restore the table from backup.

If you don't have one - then you need to extract records from the A.ibd or ibdata1